# How to retrieve data batch wise from sql table?

Tags: c#, sql

I have large data which I want to retrieve in batch it's say 1000 records per batch from sql database using c#. Is there any way of doing it?

Sql table has 5 columns and total 8000 records

Comment: Could you please add your existing code that fetches the data from db? The answer to this question depends on the technology you use to access the database - SQL, Entity Framework, Dapper, ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if my understanding is correct, then you use the below sample code for your requirement:

```
SELECT column-names
  FROM table-name
 ORDER BY column-names
OFFSET n ROWS
 FETCH NEXT m ROWS ONLY
```

This uses Offset and Fetch next concept. you need pass n and m values from C# code. for example, you can set n as 1 and m as 1000 , it will fetch you first 1000 records from the DB. You can take this to start with and do changes in C# and modify above Snippet to achieve your requirement.